# PHP - How Get specific data from Facebook Page Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following PHP code :

```
<?php
require_once 'library/facebook.php';
include '../constants.php';

define('TOKEN_FILE', 'fb_page_accestoken.txt'); // dont need to change this
$fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$access_token = file_get_contents('fb_app_token.txt');

$response  = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token;
echo $response;

?>
```

The above creates a URL to access my Facebook Graph API. When I copy it and paste it in the browser url I get the following:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "category": "Media/news/publishing",
         "name": "My Sandbox",
         "access_token": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456",
         "perms": [
            "ADMINISTER",
            "EDIT_PROFILE",
            "CREATE_CONTENT",
            "MODERATE_CONTENT",
            "CREATE_ADS",
            "BASIC_ADMIN"
         ],
         "id": "123456789"
      },
```

How can I extract particular information such as the access_token value in my php file?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I was aware of that. When I tried `var_dump(json_decode($response));
var_dump(json_decode($response, true));` Nothing worked

Comment: what your $response shows ?

Comment: It displays nothing - I get the following error _PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in ****** on line 26_

Comment: Use this $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("your url end point",true); and then print_r($response); see what you get

Comment: Also you need to have manage_pages permission for the user for which you are trying to access the data

Comment: Ok its displaying the arrays... how can I now display the access_token only please?

Comment: can you post the array I will create the code

Comment: stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [category] => Media/news/publishing [name] => Sandbox [access_token] => abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456 [perms] => Array ( [0] => ADMINISTER [1] => EDIT_PROFILE [2] => CREATE_CONTENT [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT [4] => CREATE_ADS [5] => BASIC_ADMIN ) [id] => 123456789 ))

Comment: See my answer, the array that you gave me is in object form you need to use json_decode($data,true) to get proper array

Comment: That is what I did but it still gives me the same output `$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($responsez,true));

print_r($response);`

Comment: I have updated my answer to use your code responsez = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token);
    $response  =  json_decode(responsez,true); please check now it should work.

Comment: It still gave me the same layout :-(

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, that you are appending the URL to $response.. not the content!
Do:

```
$response = file_get_contents("http..");
```

& use:

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```

to get the response as a php object.
You can then access your values normally:

```
$access_token = $response->access_token;
```

Comment: Hi, when I `echo $response->access_token;` nothing is being displayed after following your modificaitons.

Comment: do var_dump($response); die; to see the content of the variable.. what does it output?

Comment: Now its giving me null

Comment: Make sure you replaced the "http://.." with your complete url + request token. var_dump this before using json_decode.. it should contain the json object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Your code needs to be this way, you are still not doing json_decode($jsondata,true);
Here is the correct code.

```
define('TOKEN_FILE', 'fb_page_accestoken.txt'); // dont need to change this
$fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$access_token = file_get_contents('fb_app_token.txt');
$responsez = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token);
$response  =  json_decode($responsez,true);
```

The above will return an array.

From that array you can display the access token as

```
$data =   $response['data'];
echo $data['access_token'];
```

or directly as

```
echo $response['data']['access_token'];
```

If you do not want json_decode() as array then just do as

```
define('TOKEN_FILE', 'fb_page_accestoken.txt'); // dont need to change this
    $fb = new Facebook(array(
      'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $access_token = file_get_contents('fb_app_token.txt');
    $responsez = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token);
    $response  =  json_decode($responsez);

echo $response->data->access_token ;
```

You can also use the Graph api calls as

```
define('TOKEN_FILE', 'fb_page_accestoken.txt'); // dont need to change this
$fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$access_token = file_get_contents('fb_app_token.txt');
$params = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token
   );

$response = $fb->api('me/accounts','GET',$params);
```

Your response will have the data

NOTE : Make sure that this api end point requires manage_pages permission

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/

Comment: Hi, it gives me _PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in_ and the output as _Array_

Comment: This line gives you what Please post it $responsez = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token);

Comment: I have created a test page how json encode and decode works http://codepad.org/Mjb9A8as

Comment: I have updated the answer again you can do as $responsez = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token);
    $response  =  json_decode($responsez);

echo $response->data->access_token ;

Comment: Hi, did you update it as your code is like mine exactly. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if you are getting the response from file_get_contents("graph api url") and if you do json_decode to that response you should be able to get the data you wanted.